# Selenium: Matching content of dynamic div

Tags: selenium

I have a div that is dynamic. It's id is "logo" and it actually contains different logo based on the url I use. For example :-

```
<div id="header-container"> 
  <div id="header"> 
    <a href="/demo/"><div id="logo"></div></a>
```

header.css file contain the logo div in detail

```
#logo {
width: 315px;
height: 88px;
background: url('/media/images/qt/Butto_qt.png') no-repeat -1339px 0px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}
```

I can invoke click on the xpath

```
"//div[@id='header-container']/div[@id='header']/a/div[@id='logo']" .
```

However, what I want to figure out is how can I verify if the url contains "Butto_qt.png" ? If it is possible, how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a bit of Javascript:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('hlogo').childNodes[1]).backgroundImage
```

That should work in modern browsers.

Using selenium, you would use the `assertEval` method. For example, if you are using the PHPUnit Selenium extension:

```
$this->assertEval("window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('hlogo').childNodes[1]).backgroundImage",'Butto_qt.png');
```